# Receiving an error about properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to Compare two users (CopyFromUser) and (CopyToUser), get the missing groups of the (Copytouser), display the groups and select which ones I want to add the (copytouser) to.

Receiving this Error: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

More about the error: The Out-Gridview works and shows the groups, and I can select which one but it doesn't Add-ADgroupmember it triggers the error.

Powershell Code:

```
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser usertest -prop MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser dsstest -prop MemberOf

$MissingGroups = Compare-Object $CopyFromUser $CopyToUser -Property MemberOf | ? SideIndicator -eq '<='

$GroupsObj = $MissingGroups.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup –prop Description | Select Name,Description

$GroupsObj | Out-GridView -PassThru | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUser
```

Expectation is that I can use the Out-GridView -PassThru to select which groups that I want to add my CopyToUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison should only compare the list of groups the user is a member of - not the user object itself using the property "MemberOf".

Something like this should work:

```
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser -Identity usertest -Properties MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser -Identity dsstest -Properties MemberOf

$MissingGroups = 
    Compare-Object $CopyFromUser.MemberOf $CopyToUser.MemberOf | 
        Where-Object -Property SideIndicator -EQ -Value '<='
            

$GroupsObj = 
    $MissingGroups.InputObject | 
        Get-ADGroup -Properties Description | 
            Select-Object Name,Description

($GroupsObj | 
    Out-GridView -PassThru ).Name | 
        Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUser
```

Comment: `.Name` will fail there if in their domain they don't use Name = SamAccountName or one of the attributes mentioned in `-Identity`. At least one of the attributes must be preserved

Comment: I tested it in my domain and it just worked. ‍♂️

Comment: Do the Name and SamAccountName match in your Domain? If yes, then that is why it didnt fail

Comment: ... it seems like ... ‍♂️ ... lucky me ... 

Answer (score 1):

The issue happens because you're using `Select Name, Description` and **`Add-ADGroupMember` does not know what to do with an pipeline object having those 2 properties.** You must preserve at least 1 of the properties that can be bound from pipeline to [`-Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-identity) then expand on that property before piping to `Add-ADGroupMember`:

- A distinguished name
- A GUID (objectGUID)
- A security identifier (objectSid)
- Security Accounts Manager account name (sAMAccountName)

Aside, your previous logic can be simplified by using the Active Directory filter, there is no need for `Compare-Object` or anything else. **Just query AD for any group that has `$CopyFromUser` as a member and does not have `$CopyToUser` as a member.**

```bash
$CopyFromUser = (Get-ADUser usertest).DistinguishedName
$CopyToUser = (Get-ADUser dsstest).DistinguishedName

$getADGroupSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(&(member=$CopyFromUser)(!member=$CopyToUser))"
    Properties = 'Description'
}

Get-ADGroup @getADGroupSplat |
    Select-Object Name, Description, DistinguishedName |
    Out-GridView -PassThru |
    ForEach-Object DistinguishedName |
    Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUser
```